# import error - matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3

I'm kind of new to RPi. I need to plot a data stream received on some of GPIO pins. I've decided to use `matplotlib` for the project. however I'm stuck at stage 1: install and import `matplotlib`!
I've already checked [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/74120/problem-with-matplotlib) and [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15420/how-to-install-python3-matplotlib-on-raspi). but when I try to run `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` with either `python` or `python3`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from matplotib import pyplot as plt
ImportError: No module named 'matplotib'
```

any help as to how to properly install and import `matplotib` (preferably with `python3`) is greatly appreciated.
also if there is another package that is easier to install and use, I'd like to know ;).

**EDIT:** I'm using rasbian Stretch (release date: Release date: 2018-04-18) from [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/%22here%22) on RaspberryPi 3B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`No module named 'matplotib'` looks like a simple typo in your python script. Change `matplotib` (a "l" is missing) to `matplotlib` and it should work.

Comment: that was probably the dumbest mistake I've made, :D
thanks a lot